# How to Add Click Listeners to Inflated XML Buttons?

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, layout-inflater

I am implementing [Pakerfeldts' viewflow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) (Specifically the 'DiffViewFlowExample') in my main activity and I cant figure how to add click listeners to ImageButtons that are in my inflated views.

So how do I add a click listener to the image button w/an @id=regulatoryDocsBtn located in the dashboard_view?

Below are code snippets & I thank you in advance for any help.

Main Activity Class:

```
public class Home extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  /**
   * Setup the ViewFlow
   * w/TitleFlow------------------------------------------
   */
   ViewFlow viewFlow = (ViewFlow) findViewById(R.id.viewflow);
   DiffAdapter vfAdapter = new DiffAdapter(this);
   viewFlow.setAdapter(vfAdapter);

   TitleFlowIndicator indicator = (TitleFlowIndicator) findViewById(R.id.viewflowindic);
   indicator.setTitleProvider(vfAdapter);
   viewFlow.setFlowIndicator(indicator);
}
```

DiffAdapter Class:Note:The inflated views are @ the bottom of this class.

```
public class DiffAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements TitleProvider {

private static final int VIEW1 = 0;
private static final int VIEW2 = 1;
private static final int VIEW_MAX_COUNT = VIEW2 + 1;
private final String[] names = { "DashBoard", "ToolBox" };

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public DiffAdapter(Context context) {
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override(S)...............

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
int view = getItemViewType(position);
if (convertView == null) {
    switch (view) {
    case VIEW1:
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_view, null);
    break;
    case VIEW2:
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbox_view, null);
    break;
    }
}
return convertView;
}
```

A Snippet of one of the views:dashboard_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#10000000"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <!-- Row 1 -->

    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/regulatoryDocsBtn"
                style="@style/dashBoardimageBtn"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_regulatory" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/dashBoardTxt"
                android:layout_below="@id/regulatoryDocsBtn"
                android:text="Regulatory Docs" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        .....
        </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the property `onClick` to the button in the xml, indicating the name of the method to execute.

The method must have a `View` param.

For example:

In XML layout:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/testButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:onClick="testClick" />
```

In Activity code:

```
public void testClick(View v) {
    // The code to be executed on click
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The simplicity of things that I didn't know about.  THNX!!  This worked. Here is a link on how its used: [Easier click listeners](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html) @ the bottom of the blog.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to get the button using

```
ImageButton rdb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.regulatoryDocsBtn);
```

and add a listener to it:

```
rdb.setOnClickListener(new RdbOnClickListener());
...

class RdbOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
         //do what you gotta do
    }
}
```

or simply:

```
rdb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
         //do what you gotta do
    }
});
```

That should do it. It's all in the example in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#CustomButton) :)

Comment: That's what I originally tried & thought but it doesn't work - just NPE. Thnx though.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Because it should work :) You should call findViewById() in your activity, or do sth like activity.findViewById(..).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Button` use `TextView` and write click listener on that `TextView`.